# When does AWS Glue job send a STARTING event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a glue job and want to get an email alert when a job starts running. According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/automating-awsglue-with-cloudwatch-events.html) a Glue job will send "Glue Job Run Status" events to Eventbridge such as "STARTING" AND "RUNNING".

I have an EventBridge rule set up to monitor for a "STARTING" event from my glue job and then communicate with an SNS topic to send an email but the event never matches. I also tried monitoring for "RUNNING" events instead but the EventBridge rule also never matched on that. I am able to successfully send an email when I monitor for the "FAILED" job status.

What conditions will cause a Glue job to emit either a "STARTING" or "RUNNING" event to EventBridge? I tried kicking off a glue job by clicking "Run" button in AWS console and through an on demand trigger but no luck.